# Differences between TdOleDb and Teradata .NET provider

Tags: sql, oledb, teradata

In converting some of our old apps from the TdOleDb provider to the .NET provider, I've discovered a number of differences in the SQL that's supported.  One of two examples I've come across are how TdOleDb allows this:

```
substring('abcd',2,2)
```

The .NET provider, however, throws an exception.  You have to convert it to one of Teradata's two supported substring functions like this:

```
substr('abcd',2,2)
substring('abcd' from 2, 2)
```

Is there a way to identify all known differences in how the parser works between these two providers?  We certainly plan on testing everything, but we could miss one or two SQL executions, so being able to search our apps for unsupported SQL would be a great help.

**Edit**

Here's the other example I found where the two providers behave differently.  This is the old OleDb code that is executing a macro with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`:

```
cmdQuote = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
cmdQuote.Connection = conQuote

cmdQuote.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdQuote.CommandText = "mydb.mymacro"
```

When I change all of the OleDb classes to those of the .NET provider, Teradata throws this exception:

```
[Teradata Database] [5494] 'mymacro' is not a stored procedure
```

To get it to work with the .NET provider, I have to convert it to this:

```
cmdQuote = New TdCommand
cmdQuote.Connection = conQuote

cmdQuote.CommandText = "execute mydb.mymacro(?)"
cmdQuote.Parameters.Add(MyParam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like OleDB supports (at least some) ODBC-syntax, see

[Scalar Functions](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/Connectivity/B035_2509_034K/2509ch06.08.22.html#ww13919714)

Comment: Good document reference, but Teradata also supports `substring`.  It's just that it's syntatcical use is different.  `substr` shares the same syntactical signature, but it has a different name.  I will update my question with the other example I found.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Teradata only supports `SUBSTRING(x FROM n FOR m)` or `SUBSTR(x,m,n)`, but `SUBSTRING(x,m,n)` is invalid and rewritten by the ODBC driver. I wouldn't expect any other functions in OleDb besides those found in ODBC.